# How to get id from StatefulWidget in State?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to *load comments in my post here*. For that I need to send post id to my HTTP get request. post **id** I sent **from another page**. but I want to assign that  `String id;` value to `final response = await http.get("http://$ip:$apiPort/solutions/$id");` here id in **Flutter**.

How can I do that?

[to clear what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ical8.jpg)

my code is

```
class Solutions  extends StatefulWidget {
  String id ;
  final bool isEditMode;

  Solutions({
    this.id,
    this.isEditMode,
  });
  @override
  _SolutionsState createState() => _SolutionsState();
}

class _SolutionsState extends State<Solutions> {
 List data;
 var ip = Configuration.yourIp;
 var apiPort = Configuration.yourApiPort;

    Future<List> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://$ip:$apiPort/solutions/$id");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
     this.getData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Future<List> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://$ip:$apiPort/solutions/${widget.id}");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

This should to the trick.

From the State class (`_SolutionState` in your case), you can access the widget (`Solution` in your case) members by finding them in `widget`.

**BONUS**
Your `id` should be `final`, since `StatefulWidget` is marked as an `immutable` class, which means its members should all be `final`. You have surely a warning about this from your IDE.